# Función no muestra datos

Tags: mysql, funciones

estoy aprendiendo a realizar funciones y métodos en mysql, pero al momento de realizar una función, se crea normal enviando los parámetros de forma implicita en el código, pero cuando le envió un parámetro está no muestra información de la consulta, no muestra error asociado por sintaxís.
Este es el código de la función:

Nota:enunciado:Obtener el sueldo promedio de los profesores de la categoria 1.

```
delimiter $$

create function PromedioProfesoresXCategoria() returns varchar(20)

BEGIN

    declare cate int;
    declare prom int;
    declare resp varchar(20);

    set cate = (select cate_prof from profesor where  cate_prof = 1);
    set prom = (select avg(sal_prof) as Sueldo_Promedio from profesor where cate_prof = (select cate_prof from profesor where  cate_prof = 1));
    set resp =(select concat(cate, "->" ,prom));

    return resp;
END
$$ delimiter ;

select PromedioProfesoresXCategoria() as Promedio_Categoria;
```

Cuando le creó una variable para que me reciba este dato no muestra nada

```
declare cp int;
```

para cuando ejecute le envió el valor 2, que comparará la categoria 2 de los  profesores

```
.
.
.
create function PromedioProfesoresXCategoria(cp int) returns varchar(20)
.
.
.
.

select PromedioProfesoresXCategoria() as Promedio_Categoria;
```

Comment: Deberías declarar el parámetro en la función.

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@. En tu primer código, me parece que tu función no recibe el parámetro que le envías (la Categoría), porque no has declarado el parámetro al crear la función. En la segunda parte, vuelves a mostrarnos la creación de la función, pero esta vez sí declaras el parámetro (`cp`). Pero en ninguna de las veces que invocas la función, envías el valor a la función. ¿Cuál de las dos declaraciones es la definitiva?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer la función bastante más simple

```
    DECLARE prom INT;
    Set prom = (SELECT AVG(sal_prof) FROM profesor WHERE cate_prof=1);
    return prom
```

Esto te debe dar el promedio (redondeado, porque usas enteros) de profesores con categoria 1.

Answer (score 0):

delimiter $$

create function PromedioProfesoresXCategoria() returns varchar(20)

BEGIN

```
declare cate int;
declare prom int;
declare resp varchar(20);

set cate = (select cate_prof from profesor where  cate_prof = 1);
set prom = (select avg(sal_prof) as Sueldo_Promedio from profesor where cate_prof = (select cate_prof from profesor where  cate_prof = 1));
set resp =(select concat(cate, "->" ,prom));

return resp;
```

END
$$ delimiter ;

select PromedioProfesoresXCategoria() as Promedio_Categoria;

función que no recibe parámetros

delimiter $$

create function PromedioProfesoresXCategoria(int cp) returns varchar(20)

BEGIN

```
declare cate int;
declare prom int;
declare resp varchar(20);

set cate = (select cate_prof from profesor where  cate_prof = cp);
set prom = (select avg(sal_prof) as Sueldo_Promedio from profesor where cate_prof = (select cate_prof from profesor where  cate_prof = cp));
set resp =(select concat(cate, "->" ,prom));

return resp;
```

END
$$ delimiter ;

select PromedioProfesoresXCategoria(1) as Promedio_Categoria;

Bueno atendiendo sus comentarios, en la primera forma como declare la función sin datos que reciba. En la segunda declaración le envió el parámetro para que realice la comparación de la categoría con este valor. No se si me estoy dando a entender.